# How to safely convert columns with dates represented as strings to unix timestamps using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, unix-timestamp

I have following data frame:

```
       dteday

0      2011-01-01
1      2011-01-02
2      2011-01-03
3      2011-01-04
4      2011-01-05
5      2011-01-06
6      2011-01-07
7      2011-01-08
8      2011-01-09
9      2011-01-10
10     2011-01-11
11     2011-01-12
12     2011-01-13
13     2011-01-14
14     2011-01-15
15     2011-01-16
16     2011-01-17
```

And want to transform this column to column of Unix timestamps of this date.

I tried this, but ran into next error:

`df['tmstamp'] = df.dteday.astype(np.int64)`

Error:`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2011-01-01'`

I can't find the same questions anywhere.
What's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Timestamp can refer to several things. Are you looking to get UNIX epoch timestamps from dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your current code is trying to directly convert the string `2011-01-01` to an integer i.e. `np.int64`. The parsing/conversion fails thus you're seeing an error.

You can use `pd.to_datetime()` method to convert the string values in the column to datetime object first. ([Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)). Then you can convert the type to `np.int64`.

Given the following dataframe:

```py
        dates
0  2011-01-01
1  2011-01-02
2  2011-01-03
3  2011-01-04
4  2011-01-05
```

Try this:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']).astype(np.int64)
```

Outputs:

```
        dates            timestamp
0  2011-01-01  1293840000000000000
1  2011-01-02  1293926400000000000
2  2011-01-03  1294012800000000000
3  2011-01-04  1294099200000000000
4  2011-01-05  1294185600000000000
```